# WCF - I have been given a SOAP request and I need to create a SOAP web service to consume this SOAP request

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-binding, wcf-security

The sample SOAP request will come through like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope>
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa=http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                    <wsse:Username>soapUserName</wsse:Username>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:To>https://wcfexample.com/Service.svc</wsa:To>
        <wsa:MessageID>ABC123</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>SoapRQ</wsa:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ABC>
        <DETAIL>
            ...
        </DETAIL>
    </ABC>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Body of the soap envelope is xml, which I think would be best handled as a string and then I can serialise this once it hits the server.

I think the trickiest thing for me is setting up the configuration of WCF to handle the security portion of this.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The wcf setting security section usually selects the binding you want, then sets a security mode for the binding, and on the client side you can also set the client credential type. You can refer to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/programming-wcf-security) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've gone through that doc and also a lot of other MS Learn documentation but not too sure how to get the soap header security portion in that soap request.

Comment: You can implement [IDispatchMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) interface, using two methods AfterReceiveRequest and BeforeSendReply to get the header security. You can follow the example in this link.